# I am getting error while running the rspec test case for API results at particular subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting

> bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)

error while running the below code at line

> get :show, id: owner.id, format: :json, subdomain: 'api'

```
describe Api::V1::OwnersController, :type => :controller do
  render_views
  #before { host! "api.localhost:3000" }
  let(:owner) {FactoryGirl.create(:owner)}

  before(:each) do
    request.host = "api.localhost:3000"
  end

  describe "GET #show" do
    it "returns the information about an Owner on a hash" do
      # TODO get this working
      get :show, id: owner.id, format: :json, subdomain: 'api'
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
      #owner_response = JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)
      #expect(owner_response[:email]).to eql @owner.email
    end
  end
end
```

I am adding a subdomain to render the API results here.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am getting error while running this rspec at line "get :show, id: owner.id, format: :json, subdomain: 'api'"

Comment: Rails 5? https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/04/19/changes-to-test-controllers-in-rails-5.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
get :show, params: { id: owner.id, format: :json, subdomain: 'api' }
```